# How to use GraphQL Fragments across multiple (typescript) files

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo-client

I am trying to DRY up my schema, and am starting to use fragments, and **I am having an issue referencing fragments across files.**

stack: typescript / apollo client / graphql-tag

In subject.ts:

```
export const SUBJECT_FRAGMENT = gql`
  fragment SubjectFields on Subject {
    id
    name
    slug
    description
  }
`;
```

In tracker.ts:

```
export const TRACKER_FRAGMENT = gql`
  fragment TrackerFields on Tracker {
    id
    name
    slug
    purpose
    type
  }
`;
```

also in tracker.ts:

```
import { SUBJECT_FRAGMENT } from './subjects';
export const trackerQuery = gql`
  query TrackerQuery($id: ID!) {
    tracker(trackerId: $id) {
      ...TrackerFields
      subjects {
        ...SubjectFields
      }
    }
  }
  ${TRACKER_FRAGMENT}
  ${SUBJECT_FRAGMENT}
`;
```

When trackerQuery gets executed the ${SUBJECT_FRAGMENT} is returning `undefined` but ${TRACKER_FRAGMENT} works as expected.

Can someone point me to what I am potentially doing wrong with my qgl or my imports?

Thank you!!

Comment: Hrrmm:  I wonder if this has to do with: https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-tag/issues/240

Comment: Note:  When I put all of my fragments in a one fragments.ts file it works fine

Comment: Shouldn't you export unparsed fragments? As it stands in your code, fragments will be parsed once before being exported and a second time when they're included in a query?

Comment: @Jaxx -- can you elaborate -- do you mean I should not wrap the fragments with the  `gql` function?

Comment: Yes! Try exporting them as simple multiline strings (so, still wrapped with backquotes).